# What version of Gutenberg is included with WordPress?

Tags: block-editor

Gutenberg is developed separately https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg and the latest version currently is `7.2.0`.

How to find out which version of Gutenberg is included in my WordPress installation?

Answer (score 7):

You can find the versions in WordPress here with this recently created document: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/principles/versions-in-wordpress/ You weren't alone in wanting to have this information :) As mentioned above, it can be tricky to directly line up versions but this is the closest approximation currently. When WordPress 5.5 is launched, this document will be updated.

Answer (score 1):

The code that goes into core doesn’t necessarily reflect the exact code that is in a specific version of the Gutenberg plugin which is why it is hard to determine which version of Gutenberg is included in the core WordPress.

Comment: Please be more specific and explain the differences. :)

Answer (score 0):

*edit: (already answered by anne :))*

The [versions in WordPress page](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/handbook/versions-in-wordpress/) lists which will provide a range.
For a release of WordPress core, features from Gutenberg plugin are taken from several different versions.

Comment: The block editor has continued its rapid iteration since WordPress 5.0, and now has Gutenberg version 6.5 bundled with WordPress 5.3; that’s TWELVE releases all bundled into 5.3 (versions 5.4, 5.5, 5.6, 5.7, 5.8, 5.9, 6.0, 6.1, 6.2, 6.3, 6.4, and 6.5)! Bug fixes and performance improvements from Gutenberg versions 6.6 and 6.7 will also be part of 5.3

Comment: There is no definite way to tell which features of Gutenberg would be available in which version of WordPress.

Comment: Good clarification ;and this is being tracked at https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/48329